# How to correctly pause AudioTrack and resume playing smoothly?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I am using Android's `AudioTrack` to play a PCM file recorded earlier. If I don't pause while playing, everything is fine; but if I pause and resume, a large chunk of audio (about 1 second) is skipped. Here is my code:

```
// Player thread
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,
                    bufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

audioTrack.play();

FileInputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int offset = 0;

while (true) {
    if(paused) { continue;}

    int cnt = 0;
    try {
       cnt = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    } catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(cnt < 0) break;
    audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, cnt);
    audioTrack.play();
}
audioTrack.release();
```

And here is code to pause and resume playing:

```
public void pause(){
    this.paused = true;
    audioTrack.pause();
}

public void resume(){
    this.paused = false;
}
```

What goes wrong? What is the correct way to do `pause`?

Comment: Are you calling `audioTrack.play();` in the main thread (Activity/Fragment class) without any service?

Comment: I would advise wrapping the audio track play code in a service class in the background thread. then, you can achieve play/pause functionality with the help of broadcast receivers.

Comment: No, the first part of code is wrapped in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `write` is returning a short transfer count. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#write(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))

> ...if the track is stopped or paused on entry... then the write may return a short transfer count.

Your code does not address this edge case, therefor it's likely that an entire buffer's worth of audio is simply being dropped.

A simple solution might be to attempt a second `write`, immediately after the `play()`, but only in the event the first `write` returns a short count. This second `write` would need to account for exactly those bytes that were not written during the first `write`.